# View database entries created by factory_girl in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Is it possible to view the database entries (for example with PhpMyAdmin) which were created by a factory? My tests are successful, so the Database entry should exist. But when i add sleep(60) to my test (after creating the entry), i can't find any database entries in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most setups for FactoryGirl, your database entries will be inserted in a transaction that is never committed. That means the records will never be visible outside that one test.

If you're using RSpec, you can set `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false`.

If you're using DatabaseCleaner, you can use `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation`.

After doing this, the transaction will be committed and records will be visible outside the test. This will likely make your tests a little slower.